# How to get a input a boolean value from the user?

Tags: python

how to get a boolean value from the user, if its not a boolean value the loop runs until it gets a boolean value(True/false)

Comment: It really depends on how you interpret the input. A user may enter `y`, `yes`, or anything else and then you use conditionals `if user_input == 'yes': val = True`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to only input `True` or `False` Then Use this...

```py
while True:
    user_in = input("Write True OR False:> ")
    if user_in in ['True','False']: # OR ['True','False','true','false']
        print("User input bool values.")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect Type, Try Again.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd read a value from the user as a string, and then compare it to values you consider true or false.

If you try `bool(input())` the only thing that will be `False` is empty input.

Tip: if you're looking for a particular value, like `true` from your user, you may want to convert to lowercase to make case-insensitive checks easier.

```
if input().lower() == 'true':
    ...
else:
    ...
```

If you wish to accept only `'true'` or `'false'` I suggest creating a function to do that.

```
def read_bool(prompt='', err_msg=None, true='true', false='false', case_insensitive=True):
    while True:
        val = input(prompt)
        if case_insensitive:
            val = val.lower()
            true = true.lower()
            false = false.lower()
        if val == true:
            return True
        elif val == false:
            return False
        elif err_msg:
            print(err_msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the value submitted by the user equals to True or False

```
val == 'True'
val == 'False'
```

This is string comparison but the result of the comparison is a boolean value.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the input is `True`, `true` or `False`, `false` by use the **lower** method

###### Here is the code:

```
close = False
while not close:
    # Your code here
    if input().lower() in ["true", "false"]:
        close = True
```

Comment: How would you know what the input was when the *while* loop terminates?